# Permutation test versus a Wilcoxon signed-rank test

Tags: r, wilcoxon-signed-rank, permutation-test

I have data on arrival order for two individuals and I want to determine if one (y) is arriving consistently later than the other (x).

```
x<-c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,1)
y<-c(2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2)
```

So in 10 out of 14 cases in my example y arrives after x.

Is it more appropriate to use a permutation test or the Wilcoxon signed-rank test here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signed rank test makes no sense because you can't rank the absolute differences -- they're *all* 1.

Also $y=3-x$ so all the information is in $x$. The $y$ values add nothing.

Assuming independence and constant probability of $x$ being first across trials, in effect you're looking at a sign test (binomial test of proportion); if you look at $s=2x-3$ you have the signs of the differences. Alternatively if you look at $b=x-1$ then the $b_i$ will be Bernoulli($\frac{_1}{^2}$) under the null, and $\sum_i b_i$ will be $\text{binomial}(n,\frac{_1}{^2})$

The x-values are *already* ranks, so a permutation test based on the x-values will be identical to the sign test/binomial test.

In the vanilla distribution of R that's easiest done by `binom.test`.